# forcing synchronous javascript using closures

Tags: javascript

This code hangs.

I am reasonably sure it's because the response in the anonymous function is a new variable not connected with the outer scope. How do I solve this?

```
function foo() { //...

    var url = "http://urliciously-urlish-url"
    response = null;
    $.get(url, function (data) {response = data;
                               });

    while( response === null)
    {
        1;
    }
    console.log(response);

    //...
}
```

*Note* I am aware that this design will (as usual for polling systems) hang the page until response becomes non-null. That's OK in this context.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your $.get is returning things?

Comment: The answers below are correct - and generally, writing asynchronously is what you should do - but a quick point of contention: Just because the url is correct, doesn't mean that it isn't wise to use chrome inspector, fiddler, or something else to confirm that you are getting data.

Comment: @CrisCarew: I did check, that's how I knew. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous.  If you *really* want this to be synchronous, you'll have to use the `$.ajax` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        response = data;
    }
});
```

That being said, I agree with cHao -- you should get used to writing asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

While your code is running, the event handlers won't.

Translation: This code won't work.

If you want to use JS, you'll almost definitely have to get used to writing asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that the callback will never be executed because the JS thread is still running. It will wait for the current context to be ended, before it goes on executing the "next tick" (the callback here). Between the ticks it may also update DOM and handle other things.

Instead of using a hanging loop, use a [synchronous ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Synchronous_request) (yes, thats possible). In jQuery: [`{async:false}`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). However, it then will "only" hang until the request is ended - which maybe never happens. And unresponsable GUI is the worst thing to happen, so DO NOT USE it.